# SQL - If variable1 is null select variable2

Tags: php, mysql

```
"INSERT INTO `tableA`(
        `log_id`,
        `customer_id`,
        `order_id`,
        `message`,
        `payment_method`,
        `processed`,
        `date_added`
    )
    SELECT
        'null',
        `customer_id`,
        `order_id`,
        '$data[11]',
        '$data[6]',
        'yes',
        '$data[1]'

    FROM
        `tableB`,
        `tableC`
    WHERE
        `customer_id` = '$data[8]' AND `order_id` = '$data[7]'";
```

In this query if `$data[11]` is empty or null i want to insert `$data[9]` for that. 
default value must be $data[11] and i want to use $data[9] only if $data[11] is null or empty. 
Hope for SQL or PHP solution.

Comment: Check out MySQL's [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 1):

Use NVL function, which returns default value if the first one is NULL. In Oracle db it would be like following:

```
 SELECT
    ...
    NVL('$data[11]', '$data[9]'),
```

In MySql:

```
SELECT
    ...
    IFNULL('$data[11]', '$data[9]'),
```